# laravel voyager mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, voyager

i'm trying to save array in database in laravel voyager admin panel so i added

```
   protected $casts = [
   'array_value' => 'array',
   ];
```

to my model but now I get this error:

```
mb_strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Dev-College\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\bread\browse.blade.php)
```

Comment: How is the code in your controller where you save?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

This is likely happening to you because in DataRowsTableSeeder the field for settings is named `locale` which is not the name in the DB.

I think this is a known issue (Voyager #3102).  You can find more information and some tweaks to resolve your issue at the [gitHub issues page](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/issues/3102)